# Should I allow users to manage their profile using the admin application?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Maybe my question can sound a little bit stupid but it's a real one.

I'm doing an ecommerce website, so as an admin I directly use the one provided by django, to manage my article and user.

But, what's the best for my user? Should I let them use the admin panel to manage their profile? (I saw I can manage who can do what on the admin panel). Or should i create a small member area to let them manage their account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code the "member area" to be much more user-friendly than Django's admin, inevitably very general purpose.  You can carefully restrict exactly what a user can change, saving them from mistakes that could be damaging and hard to fix, add more sanity checks too.

All in all, I'd say that, while more work, coding your own "member area" is a far superior option than trying to shoehorn things into the (inevitably!) "one size fits all" Django admin arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make these users as 'superusers' in admin, to manage.
And you can override view in admin to make it more friendly. Good luck!